# C# FtpWebRequest - special character "§" in password

Tags: c#, ftp, passwords, character, ftpwebrequest

I have got a problem using FtpWebRequest with the special character "§" in password.
The code looks like this:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://ftphost"));
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
reqFTP.EnableSsl = false;
reqFTP.Timeout = 60000;
reqFTP.UseBinary = false;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pa§");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

The GetResponse()-Method fails with "530 User cannot log in".
With FileZilla the login works.

I traced the network traffic with Wireshark and noticed the following:

- FileZilla converts the password to "pa\302\247", tries to log in and fails. After that FileZilla retries connecting with password "pa\247" which succeeds.
- The FtpWebRequest converts the password to "pa\302\247", tries to log in and fails too and throws an Exception.

How can I force FtpWebRequest to convert the password to "pa\247" and not to "pa\302\247"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an encoding problem. The **§** character is **\302\247** in **UTF-8** and **\247** in **ISO-8859-1**. Based on the information you provided this tells me that your request is being sent with charset UTF-8 and the server is expecting ISO-8859-1. From that you've got two choices, if you have access to the ftp server you should be able to change the default char set. Otherwise you'll need to send your ftp request with the charset ISO-8859-1. I don't have time to test it but you can give the following code a shot (notice the added header):

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://ftphost"));
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
reqFTP.EnableSsl = false;
reqFTP.Timeout = 60000;
reqFTP.UseBinary = false;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pa§");
reqFTP.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thank you. The code you provided throws this Exception:
"InvalidOperationException: This collection holds response headers and cannot contain the specified request header."

I tried to add the header with:
    reqFTP.Headers.Add("ContentType: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"");
which did not throw any exception.
But it didn't solve the problem.